# Change location where LDAP data is stored

Tags: ldap, centos7, openldap

I'm running an openLDAP server version 2.4.40 on CentOS 7. LDAP is going to be configured using online conf option (olc). Thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669586/where-is-my-data-directories-store-by-slapd-openldap-on-ubuntu), I know that slapd's database files are in `/var/lib/ldap`.

I'm trying to run an openLDAP server on a linux box as read-only OS partition and another partition for persistent data. I will be able to install and configure openLDAP on the OS partition, but will lose access to it after configuring it.

**Question:** Is it possible to change the location LDAP reads/writes data from */var/lib/ldap* to somewhere on the persistent data partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to move the default database of openldap after each new setup.

The steps I do when I want to move a database :

- Stop `slapd`

```
sudo service slapd stop
```

- `slapcat` the content of the `cn=config` branch in a LDIF file

```
sudo slapcat -b cn=config > /tmp/config.ldif
```

- Copy the `/var/lib/ldap` directory wherever you want it
- Make sure the user `openldap` owns the new directory and all the files inside
- Edit the previously exported LDIF to modify the `olcDbDirectory` to the new location
- Import the LDIF (Make sure the `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` is empty before doing this)

```
sudo rm -r /etc/ldap/slapd.d/*
sudo slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -b cn=config -l /tmp/config.ldif
```

- Make sure the `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` and all its content is owned by `openldap`

```
sudo chown -R openldap:openldap /etc/ldap/slapd.d/
```

- Edit needed configuration to allow Slapd to use this new database directory

For example, with `apparmor`, edit the file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.slapd` and add the following lines:

```
/path/to/new/db/ r,
/path/to/new/db/** rwk,
```

- Restart apparmor and slapd

```
sudo service apparmor restart
sudo service slapd start
```

Usually it does the trick. It's also how I backup the configuration of my openldap instances.

Answer (score 1):

I read your question in two parts:

1. You want to have the OS be read-only while preserving write access to the LDAP data
2. As a solution for #1, you propose storing the LDAP data in a location other than `/var/lib/ldap`

While I suspect #2 is possible, I don't have enough direct experience with OpenLDAP to address that directly. What I can do is suggest an alternative solution for #1. It's trivial to mount a difference disk partion at `/var/lib/ldap`, both through the `mount` command and through `fstab`. This should effectively accomplish your goal, whether or not OpenLDAP handles this natively. You might also be able to replace the `/var/lib/ldap` folder with a symlink to the desired location. Again, this bypasses OpenLDAP and any support that is or is not built into that project.

Finally, you should also think about preserving write access for certain log areas. The techniques in the paragraph above can work for moving log file locations, too.

Comment: I think your suggestion to mount the locations where data and logs are stored to some other directories on the data partition could work. I'm currently investigating where logs are stored and if I can configure the location where files are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Openldap does not appear to support moving a database, DB, file after it has been created. Openldap does not currently support deleting DB files either.

It is possible to create a new DB file and define its olcDbDirectory attribute to a path on another partition.

```
dn: olcDatabase=bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcBdbConfig
olcDatabase: bdb
olcDbDirectory: /partition/db/new-db-file
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=net
```

Information found in ch 6.1.1.4.5 [Add/Delete Databases using OLC](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html#use-databases)

Answer (score 1):

I've done this successfully and used it in AWS to retain my data when I have to refresh the machine image.
If you've rebuilt OpenLDAP with the

```
slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d
```

command (yes, we're still using the old way of config, but running it with `slapd.d` —I'm working on it)
then really all you have to do is modify the directory location in the database configuration section of slapd.conf

```
directory /data/ldap
```

Create the `DB_CONFIG` file (`chown` to `ldap:ldap`) in `/data/ldap` because LDAP will yell if it's not there.

Once you run the `slaptest` command (`slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d`), your DB will be created there.
You'll probably need to `chown -R ldap:ldap /data` and `/etc/openldap` once you're done with the `slaptest` commmand.

If this is successful your DB or DBs will be located in `/data/ldap`

Save your `slapd.conf` file on your external partition so you can import it back when you set up another server.

When you need to spin up another server, import the `slapd.conf` file and run the slaptest command.  You'll have to `chown -R ldap:ldap` to `/data` and `/etc/openldap` again, but when you start openldap, it should pick up the DBs on the external partition.

This is a solution in flux right now, but it's serving us well in standing up OpenLDAP in the cloud.  We will obviously streamline this awkward process.  We'll script all the things, maybe move `/etc/openldap` to a symlinked external drive, and modify the `slapd.d` with `ldifs` only instead of relying on the deprecated `slapd.conf`, but for now it's working fine.